# how to use simple product price in configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, price

how to use price of simple associated product in configurable product and show change price when selecting option on product view page magento 1

Answer (score 0):

Few days back I did the same and this worked for me.

You need to override `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php`

Update the method: getFinalPrice, change to

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null, $product)
{
    //Start edit
    $selectedAttributes = array();
    if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
        $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
    }
    //End edit
    if (sizeof($selectedAttributes)) return $this->getSimpleProductPrice($qty, $product);

    if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
        return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
    }

    $basePrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);
    $finalPrice = $basePrice;
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

    $finalPrice += $this->getTotalConfigurableItemsPrice($product, $finalPrice);
    $finalPrice += $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $basePrice) - $basePrice;
    $finalPrice = max(0, $finalPrice);

    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    return $finalPrice;
}
```

Then add this function right below getFinalPrice:

```
public function getSimpleProductPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        $cfgId = $product->getId();
        $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->setStoreFilter($product->getStore(), $product);
        $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
        $selectedAttributes = array();
        if ($product->getCustomOption('attributes')) {
            $selectedAttributes = unserialize($product->getCustomOption('attributes')->getValue());
        }
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $dbMeta = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT main_table.entity_id FROM {$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product')} `main_table` INNER JOIN
{$dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product_super_link')} `sl` ON sl.parent_id = {$cfgId}
SQL;
        foreach($selectedAttributes as $attributeId => $optionId) {
            $alias = "a{$attributeId}";
            $sql .= ' INNER JOIN ' . $dbMeta->getTableName('catalog/product') . "_int" . " $alias ON $alias.entity_id = main_table.entity_id AND $alias.attribute_id = $attributeId AND $alias.value = $optionId AND $alias.entity_id = sl.product_id";
        }
        $id = $db->fetchOne($sql);
        return Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id)->getFinalPrice($qty);
    }
```

Now open app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml and paste below code anywhere in file

```
<ul class="productIds" style="display:none;">
    <?php
        $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$configurableProduct);
        foreach($childProducts as $child) {
            $_productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());
            ?>
            <li id='simple_<?php echo $child->getId(); ?>'><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_productObj->getFinalPrice()); ?></li>
        <?php   
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Now open js/varien/configurable.js and change reloadPrice function as below or you can replace this whole function aswell

```
reloadPrice: function(){
    if (this.config.disablePriceReload) {
        return;
    }
    var price    = 0;
    var oldPrice = 0;
    for(var i=this.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
        if(selected.config){
            price    += parseFloat(selected.config.price);
            oldPrice += parseFloat(selected.config.oldPrice);
        }
    }

    /* Edit Code */

     //optionsPrice.changePrice('config', {'price': price, 'oldPrice': oldPrice});
     optionsPrice.reload();

     var existingProducts = new Object();
     for(var i=this.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
         var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
         if(selected.config)
         {
            for(var iproducts=0;iproducts<selected.config.products.length;iproducts++)
            {
                var usedAsKey = selected.config.products[iproducts]+"";
                if(existingProducts[usedAsKey]==undefined)
                {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey]=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey]=existingProducts[usedAsKey]+1;
                }
             }
         }
     }

     for (var keyValue in existingProducts)
     {
        for ( var keyValueInner in existingProducts)
         {
            if(Number(existingProducts[keyValueInner])<Number(existingProducts[keyValue]))
            {
                delete existingProducts[keyValueInner];
            }
         }
     }

     var sizeOfExistingProducts=0;
     var currentSimpleProductId = "";
     for ( var keyValue in existingProducts)
     {
        currentSimpleProductId = keyValue;
        sizeOfExistingProducts=sizeOfExistingProducts+1
     }

     if(sizeOfExistingProducts==1)
     {
        if($('product-price-'+this.config.productId)){
            $('product-price-'+this.config.productId).innerHTML = jQuery("#simple_"+currentSimpleProductId).html();
        }

     }
    // End Code

    return price;

    if($('product-price-'+this.config.productId)){
        $('product-price-'+this.config.productId).innerHTML = price;
    }
    this.reloadOldPrice();
},
```

You can see, in the event the user has "customized" the product (selected configurable options) we determine the associated simple product and pass control to its pricing model, otherwise if the product isn't "customized" we proceed as normal. Hope this will help you.

Comment: it changes price in checkout and cart but not changing in product view page ..

Comment: see here https://rightspots.com/test/test-configurable.html

Comment: On product view page you need to customize (using scripts) based on the dropdown change.

Comment: and upvote and accept the answer it will be useful for others who faces this problem. thanks

Comment: https://www.classyllama.com/blog/configurable-product-child-id follow this to change the price, here it has get the id on dropdown change, from id you can get the price.That's it

Comment: Check the updated answer, i have updated the script, which will change the price on dropdown..Its working code,just did now